# How to download specific files with wget and avoid creating and removing temporary files

Tags: ubuntu, download, wget

I'm using  wget to download specific files among all the files contained in a URL.

```
wget -cr -A "web_summary.html" -l 9 -np URL
```

The issue is that wget will try to download all index.html files before removing them which takes a lot of time.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you not know the URLs of the files you need up front?

Comment: I do not have the URL stored somewhere but I can have them by browsing the main URL, however this is not ideal as there are a lot of files to download and lot browsing/copy/paste to do.